# Trying to read a formatted double from text field

Tags: java, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am making a simple calculator and currently trying to fix issues with non-integers.

Got a text field `displayField` showing the results and operator buttons as well as an equal button.

Just got it working that the double results only show decimal places if there are any but I cannot get the results back into the calculation.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

private String operator;
double oldValue;
double newValue = 0;
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.###");

@FXML
private TextField displayField;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}

@FXML
private void handleDigitAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String digit = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();
    String oldText = displayField.getText();
    String newText = oldText + digit;
    displayField.setText(newText);
}

@FXML
private void handleOperator(ActionEvent event) {
    oldValue = Double.parseDouble(displayField.getText());
    displayField.setText("");
    operator = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();
}

@FXML
private void handleEqualAction(ActionEvent event) {

    switch (operator) {
        case "+":
            newValue = oldValue + Double.parseDouble(displayField.getText());
            break;
        case "-":
            newValue = oldValue - Double.parseDouble(displayField.getText());
            break;
        case "*":
            newValue = oldValue * Double.parseDouble(displayField.getText());
            break;
        case "/":
            newValue = oldValue / Double.parseDouble(displayField.getText());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    displayField.setText(String.valueOf(nf.format(newValue)));
}
```

}

The error occurs when I for example try to compute 5/2 first, get the result 2,5 and then hit an operator button.
So I assume I just have to either use an additional object to save the results or just change the line where I read from the text field (so that it also works for this changed format) but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What are the values when you are hitting the operator button the 2nd time?

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell us which locale is your application running on?

Execute

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: I see you found a solution. That's great.  That was the problem, german locale uses different format from what you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `format()` method of a `NumberFormat` (or its subclass `DecimalFormat`), you happen to be using either the default `Locale` or a `Locale` you pass the method, depending on the overload you use. As a result, you get a `Locale`-formatted output.

The same way, you should use your `DecimalFormat`'s `parse()` method to parse your display field according to the same rules.

I hope this will help...

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

I found a rather "simple" or dirty solution, which seems to work:

```
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.###", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `DecimalFormat` class to format the output. The decimal formater uses the default `Locale` which in your case is `de_DE`.
As mentioned in the above answers you can use the overloaded method of the `DecimalFormat` class to get the output in your required format.

E.g.

```
BigDecimal numerator = new BigDecimal(5);
BigDecimal denominator = new BigDecimal(2);

//In current scenario
    Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
    NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale);
    String number = format.format(numerator.divide(denominator));
    System.out.println("Parsed value is "+number); 

The output here will be 2,5
```

If you change to:

```
    Locale localeDefault = new Locale("en", "US");
    NumberFormat formatDefault = DecimalFormat.getInstance(localeDefault);
    String numberVal = formatDefault.format(numerator.divide(denominator));
    System.out.println("Parsed value is "+numberVal); 

   Output here will be 2.5
```

Hope this helps.